# In Pokemon Go how much does a Power Up increase the CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

#### In Pokemon Go how much does a Power Up increase the CP?

- In **Pokemon Go** What are the best, top tier Pokemon?
- When using a Power Up do some pokemon gain more CP than others?
- How much do they gain?

Comment: The snorlax at the gym would've had a trainer that wasn't the same level likely so you can't compare them.

Comment: @Aequitas yeah, they had to have their trainer at a much higher level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Table below in "Max Total CP" order.

*(I included the table below so there is no need to jump to a new link, or incase the original is inaccessible.)*

As you do powerups after finding a wild Pokemon, some multiple better, thus being stronger or top tire pokemon.

Multiple **your character level** by **CP per Powerup** (aka, multiplier)  to see *approximately* how much **their CP would go up**.

**Ndex** is their Pokédex number

```
| Ndex | Pokémon    | Max Total CP | Min CP/Lvl | Avg CP/Lvl | Max CP/Lvl | CP Multip/Evo | HP Base Stat | Max Total HP |
|------|------------|--------------|------------|------------|------------|---------------|--------------|--------------|
| 150  | Mewtwo     | 4144         | 53.4       | 56.8       | 60.3       |               | 106          | 179          |
| 149  | Dragonite  | 3500         | 44.6       | 47.7       | 50.9       | 2.1           | 91           | 155          |
| 151  | Mew        | 3299         | 41.9       | 44.9       | 48         |               | 100          | 169          |
| 146  | Moltres    | 3240         | 41.1       | 44.1       | 47.2       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 145  | Zapdos     | 3114         | 39.4       | 42.3       | 45.3       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 143  | Snorlax    | 3112         | 39.3       | 42.2       | 45.3       |               | 160          | 264          |
| 59   | Arcanine   | 2983         | 37.6       | 40.5       | 43.4       | 2.3           | 90           | 154          |
| 131  | Lapras     | 2980         | 37.6       | 40.4       | 43.4       |               | 130          | 217          |
| 144  | Articuno   | 2978         | 37.6       | 40.4       | 43.3       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 103  | Exeggutor  | 2955         | 37.2       | 40.1       | 43         | 2.8           | 95           | 162          |
| 134  | Vaporeon   | 2816         | 35.3       | 38.1       | 41         | 2.7           | 130          | 217          |
| 130  | Gyarados   | 2688         | 33.7       | 36.4       | 39.1       | 12.1          | 95           | 162          |
| 136  | Flareon    | 2643         | 32.9       | 35.6       | 38.5       | 2.6           | 65           | 114          |
| 6    | Charizard  | 2602         | 32.5       | 35.1       | 37.9       | 1.7           | 78           | 135          |
| 89   | Muk        | 2602         | 32.5       | 35.1       | 37.9       | 2.1           | 105          | 177          |
| 80   | Slowbro    | 2597         | 32.4       | 35.1       | 37.8       | 2.2           | 95           | 162          |
| 68   | Machamp    | 2594         | 32.4       | 35         | 37.8       | 1.5           | 90           | 154          |
| 3    | Venusaur   | 2580         | 32.2       | 34.8       | 37.6       | 1.6           | 80           | 138          |
| 9    | Blastoise  | 2542         | 31.7       | 34.3       | 37         | 1.6           | 79           | 136          |
| 71   | Victreebel | 2530         | 31.5       | 34.1       | 36.8       | 1.5           | 80           | 138          |
| 62   | Poliwrath  | 2505         | 31.2       | 33.8       | 36.5       | 1.9           | 90           | 154          |
| 45   | Vileplume  | 2492         | 31         | 33.6       | 36.3       | 1.5           | 75           | 130          |
| 31   | Nidoqueen  | 2485         | 30.9       | 33.5       | 36.2       | 1.8           | 90           | 154          |
| 34   | Nidoking   | 2475         | 30.8       | 33.3       | 36         | 1.9           | 81           | 139          |
| 36   | Clefable   | 2397         | 29.8       | 32.3       | 34.9       | 2.1           | 95           | 162          |
| 55   | Golduck    | 2386         | 29.6       | 32.1       | 34.7       | 2.2           | 80           | 138          |
| 76   | Golem      | 2303         | 28.5       | 30.9       | 33.5       | 1.6           | 80           | 138          |
| 126  | Magmar     | 2265         | 27.9       | 30.4       | 33         |               | 65           | 114          |
| 110  | Weezing    | 2250         | 27.7       | 30.2       | 32.7       | 2             | 65           | 114          |
| 112  | Rhydon     | 2243         | 27.7       | 30.1       | 32.6       | 2             | 105          | 177          |
| 139  | Omastar    | 2233         | 27.5       | 30         | 32.5       | 2.1           | 70           | 122          |
| 73   | Tentacruel | 2220         | 27.4       | 29.8       | 32.3       | 2.6           | 80           | 138          |
| 78   | Rapidash   | 2199         | 27         | 29.5       | 32         | 1.5           | 65           | 114          |
| 38   | Ninetales  | 2188         | 26.9       | 29.3       | 31.8       | 2.8           | 73           | 127          |
| 97   | Hypno      | 2184         | 26.9       | 29.3       | 31.8       | 2.1           | 85           | 146          |
| 121  | Starmie    | 2182         | 26.8       | 29.2       | 31.8       | 2.4           | 60           | 106          |
| 40   | Wigglytuff | 2177         | 26.6       | 29.1       | 31.7       | 2.5           | 140          | 233          |
| 142  | Aerodactyl | 2165         | 26.6       | 29         | 31.5       |               | 80           | 138          |
| 87   | Dewgong    | 2145         | 26.4       | 28.7       | 31.2       | 2             | 90           | 154          |
| 135  | Jolteon    | 2140         | 26.2       | 28.6       | 31.1       | 2.1           | 65           | 114          |
| 141  | Kabutops   | 2130         | 26.1       | 28.5       | 31         | 2             | 60           | 106          |
| 127  | Pinsir     | 2121         | 26         | 28.4       | 30.9       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 125  | Electabuzz | 2119         | 26         | 28.3       | 30.8       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 18   | Pidgeot    | 2091         | 25.7       | 28         | 30.4       | 1.8           | 83           | 143          |
| 94   | Gengar     | 2078         | 25.4       | 27.8       | 30.2       | 1.5           | 60           | 106          |
| 123  | Scyther    | 2073         | 25.4       | 27.7       | 30.2       |               | 70           | 122          |
| 91   | Cloyster   | 2052         | 24.9       | 27.4       | 29.9       | 2.6           | 50           | 90           |
| 115  | Kangaskhan | 2043         | 25         | 27.3       | 29.7       |               | 105          | 177          |
| 119  | Seaking    | 2043         | 25         | 27.3       | 29.7       | 2.2           | 80           | 138          |
| 26   | Raichu     | 2028         | 24.7       | 27.1       | 29.5       | 2.4           | 60           | 106          |
| 42   | Golbat     | 1921         | 23.4       | 25.6       | 28         | 3.2           | 75           | 130          |
| 49   | Venomoth   | 1890         | 23         | 25.2       | 27.5       | 1.9           | 70           | 122          |
| 82   | Magneton   | 1879         | 22.7       | 25         | 27.4       | 2.2           | 50           | 90           |
| 57   | Primeape   | 1864         | 22.6       | 24.8       | 27.1       | 2.2           | 65           | 114          |
| 128  | Tauros     | 1844         | 22.4       | 24.5       | 26.8       |               | 75           | 130          |
| 85   | Dodrio     | 1836         | 22.2       | 24.4       | 26.7       | 2.2           | 60           | 106          |
| 99   | Kingler    | 1823         | 22         | 24.2       | 26.5       | 2.4           | 55           | 98           |
| 65   | Alakazam   | 1813         | 21.9       | 24.1       | 26.4       | 1.7           | 55           | 98           |
| 28   | Sandslash  | 1810         | 21.9       | 24.1       | 26.3       | 2.4           | 75           | 130          |
| 24   | Arbok      | 1767         | 21.3       | 23.5       | 25.7       | 2.2           | 60           | 106          |
| 67   | Machoke    | 1760         | 21.2       | 23.4       | 25.6       | 1.7           | 80           | 138          |
| 47   | Parasect   | 1747         | 21         | 23.2       | 25.4       | 2             | 60           | 106          |
| 148  | Dragonair  | 1747         | 21         | 23.2       | 25.4       | 1.8           | 61           | 108          |
| 22   | Fearow     | 1746         | 21         | 23.2       | 25.4       | 2.7           | 65           | 114          |
| 114  | Tangela    | 1739         | 21         | 23.1       | 25.3       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 70   | Weepinbell | 1723         | 20.7       | 22.8       | 25.1       | 1.6           | 65           | 114          |
| 124  | Jynx       | 1716         | 20.6       | 22.8       | 25         |               | 65           | 114          |
| 117  | Seadra     | 1713         | 20.6       | 22.7       | 24.9       | 2.3           | 55           | 98           |
| 137  | Porygon    | 1691         | 20.3       | 22.4       | 24.6       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 44   | Gloom      | 1689         | 20.3       | 22.4       | 24.6       | 1.5           | 60           | 106          |
| 105  | Marowak    | 1656         | 19.8       | 21.9       | 24.1       | 1.7           | 60           | 106          |
| 101  | Electrode  | 1646         | 19.7       | 21.8       | 24         | 2             | 60           | 106          |
| 2    | Ivysaur    | 1632         | 19.5       | 21.6       | 23.8       | 1.6           | 60           | 106          |
| 53   | Persian    | 1631         | 19.5       | 21.6       | 23.7       | 2.3           | 65           | 114          |
| 108  | Lickitung  | 1626         | 19.4       | 21.5       | 23.7       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 8    | Wartortle  | 1582         | 18.9       | 20.9       | 23         | 1.6           | 59           | 105          |
| 5    | Charmeleon | 1557         | 18.5       | 20.5       | 22.7       | 1.7           | 58           | 103          |
| 77   | Ponyta     | 1516         | 17.9       | 20         | 22.1       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 107  | Hitmonchan | 1516         | 17.9       | 19.9       | 22.1       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 122  | Mr. Mime   | 1494         | 17.5       | 19.6       | 21.7       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 106  | Hitmonlee  | 1492         | 17.6       | 19.6       | 21.7       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 12   | Butterfree | 1454         | 17.2       | 19.1       | 21.2       | 3.3           | 60           | 106          |
| 20   | Raticate   | 1444         | 17         | 19         | 21         | 2.6           | 55           | 98           |
| 15   | Beedrill   | 1439         | 17         | 18.9       | 21         | 3.2           | 65           | 114          |
| 75   | Graveler   | 1433         | 16.9       | 18.8       | 20.9       | 1.7           | 55           | 98           |
| 30   | Nidorina   | 1404         | 16.6       | 18.4       | 20.4       | 1.6           | 70           | 122          |
| 93   | Haunter    | 1380         | 16.1       | 18         | 20.1       | 1.8           | 45           | 82           |
| 33   | Nidorino   | 1372         | 16.1       | 18         | 20         | 1.7           | 61           | 108          |
| 61   | Poliwhirl  | 1340         | 15.7       | 17.6       | 19.5       | 1.7           | 65           | 114          |
| 58   | Growlithe  | 1335         | 15.6       | 17.5       | 19.4       |               | 55           | 98           |
| 88   | Grimer     | 1284         | 15         | 16.8       | 18.7       |               | 80           | 138          |
| 83   | Farfetch'd | 1263         | 14.7       | 16.5       | 18.4       |               | 52           | 94           |
| 17   | Pidgeotto  | 1223         | 14.2       | 16         | 17.8       | 1.9           | 63           | 111          |
| 79   | Slowpoke   | 1218         | 14.1       | 15.9       | 17.7       |               | 90           | 154          |
| 35   | Clefairy   | 1200         | 13.9       | 15.6       | 17.5       |               | 70           | 122          |
| 111  | Rhyhorn    | 1182         | 13.6       | 15.4       | 17.2       |               | 80           | 138          |
| 51   | Dugtrio    | 1168         | 13.3       | 15.1       | 17         | 2.8           | 35           | 67           |
| 109  | Koffing    | 1151         | 13.2       | 14.9       | 16.8       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 43   | Oddish     | 1148         | 13.2       | 14.9       | 16.7       |               | 45           | 82           |
| 64   | Kadabra    | 1131         | 12.9       | 14.6       | 16.5       | 2             | 40           | 75           |
| 138  | Omanyte    | 1119         | 12.7       | 14.4       | 16.3       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 69   | Bellsprout | 1117         | 12.7       | 14.4       | 16.3       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 54   | Psyduck    | 1109         | 12.7       | 14.4       | 16.1       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 86   | Seel       | 1107         | 12.7       | 14.3       | 16.1       |               | 65           | 114          |
| 140  | Kabuto     | 1104         | 12.4       | 14.2       | 16.1       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 102  | Exeggcute  | 1099         | 12.6       | 14.2       | 16         |               | 60           | 106          |
| 66   | Machop     | 1089         | 12.4       | 14.1       | 15.9       |               | 70           | 122          |
| 133  | Eevee      | 1077         | 12.3       | 13.9       | 15.7       |               | 55           | 98           |
| 96   | Drowzee    | 1075         | 12.3       | 13.9       | 15.6       |               | 60           | 106          |
| 1    | Bulbasaur  | 1071         | 12.2       | 13.8       | 15.6       |               | 45           | 82           |
| 48   | Venonat    | 1029         | 11.7       | 13.3       | 15         |               | 60           | 106          |
| 7    | Squirtle   | 1008         | 11.4       | 13         | 14.7       |               | 44           | 81           |
| 104  | Cubone     | 1006         | 11.4       | 13         | 14.7       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 147  | Dratini    | 983          | 11.1       | 12.6       | 14.3       |               | 41           | 76           |
| 118  | Goldeen    | 965          | 10.8       | 12.4       | 14         |               | 45           | 82           |
| 4    | Charmander | 955          | 10.7       | 12.2       | 13.9       |               | 39           | 73           |
| 120  | Staryu     | 937          | 10.4       | 12         | 13.6       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 132  | Ditto      | 919          | 10.3       | 11.8       | 13.4       |               | 48           | 87           |
| 39   | Jigglypuff | 917          | 9.9        | 11.6       | 13.4       |               | 115          | 193          |
| 46   | Paras      | 916          | 10.2       | 11.7       | 13.3       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 72   | Tentacool  | 905          | 10.1       | 11.6       | 13.2       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 81   | Magnemite  | 890          | 9.7        | 11.3       | 13         |               | 25           | 51           |
| 25   | Pikachu    | 887          | 9.8        | 11.3       | 12.9       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 56   | Mankey     | 878          | 9.7        | 11.2       | 12.8       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 29   | Nidoran ?  | 876          | 9.7        | 11.2       | 12.7       |               | 55           | 98           |
| 95   | Onix       | 857          | 9.3        | 10.9       | 12.5       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 84   | Doduo      | 855          | 9.4        | 10.9       | 12.4       |               | 35           | 67           |
| 74   | Geodude    | 849          | 9.4        | 10.8       | 12.4       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 32   | Nidoran ?  | 843          | 9.3        | 10.7       | 12.3       |               | 46           | 84           |
| 100  | Voltorb    | 839          | 9.2        | 10.7       | 12.2       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 37   | Vulpix     | 831          | 9.1        | 10.6       | 12.1       |               | 38           | 71           |
| 23   | Ekans      | 824          | 9          | 10.5       | 12         |               | 35           | 67           |
| 90   | Shellder   | 822          | 8.9        | 10.4       | 12         |               | 30           | 59           |
| 92   | Gastly     | 804          | 8.7        | 10.1       | 11.7       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 27   | Sandshrew  | 798          | 8.7        | 10.1       | 11.6       |               | 50           | 90           |
| 60   | Poliwag    | 795          | 8.7        | 10.1       | 11.6       |               | 40           | 75           |
| 116  | Horsea     | 794          | 8.6        | 10         | 11.6       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 98   | Krabby     | 792          | 8.6        | 10         | 11.5       |               | 30           | 59           |
| 52   | Meowth     | 756          | 8.2        | 9.6        | 11         |               | 40           | 75           |
| 21   | Spearow    | 686          | 7.3        | 8.6        | 10         |               | 40           | 75           |
| 16   | Pidgey     | 679          | 7.3        | 8.5        | 9.9        |               | 40           | 75           |
| 113  | Chansey    | 675          | 6.3        | 8          | 9.8        |               | 250          | 407          |
| 41   | Zubat      | 642          | 6.8        | 8          | 9.4        |               | 40           | 75           |
| 63   | Abra       | 600          | 6.2        | 7.4        | 8.7        |               | 25           | 51           |
| 19   | Rattata    | 581          | 6          | 7.2        | 8.5        |               | 30           | 59           |
| 14   | Kakuna     | 485          | 4.8        | 5.9        | 7.1        | 1.1           | 45           | 82           |
| 11   | Metapod    | 477          | 4.7        | 5.8        | 7          | 1.1           | 50           | 90           |
| 50   | Diglett    | 456          | 4.1        | 5.3        | 6.6        |               | 10           | 27           |
| 13   | Weedle     | 449          | 4.4        | 5.4        | 6.5        |               | 40           | 75           |
| 10   | Caterpie   | 443          | 4.3        | 5.3        | 6.5        |               | 45           | 82           |
| 129  | Magikarp   | 262          | 2.2        | 3          | 3.8        |               | 20           | 43           |
```

---

- [Source Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xZ1daunztOgvOZxO7ABfJPF41-2mqMDzY1Qs_0OWwq8) spreadsheet from reddit TheSilphRoad
- [External Link to rankboost.com](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/tier-list/) with orignal tier info, speed of attacks and some other tid-bits.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible.

If the chart is to be believed, I am level 9, with a Jolteon, 
My Level (9) * Jolteon CP/PU Combined (30) = 270 Max CP at this level

My Jolteon's real CP is 486.

Comment: Are you trying to say that if I were to encounter a wild Jolteon, it's CP would be at most 270? This is not clearly described in your answer.

Comment: As kaizer said, your method of determining max CP doesn't work out, I get a max of 600 doing it as you said, whereas it's already at 1k and only fills up ~90% of the bar

Comment: @Kaizerwolf tried to modify what it's saying to make more clear. I said it incorrectly before, since max CP is a more complex calculation. This was just to get the general feel of which Pokemon where best.